# Grails 2.3.3 Spring Security Plugin Authentication Failed

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a Grails application I am developing that uses the Spring Security plugin version 2.0-RC2. My authentication process has been working using spring security for my login page. I just updated from Grails 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 and I am now getting the following error:

```
Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: No transactionManager bean configured
```

Has anyone else seen this when upgrading Grails with spring security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you fix the Hibernate plugin dependency? You need a new version in 2.3.3 - see http://grails.org/2.3.3+Release+Notes

Comment: Hmm... I'm not using Hibernate. I am using the MongoDB plugin instead. It looks like there was an updated version of that plugin released a couple of days ago. Will try that when I get to look at the code again tomorrow.

Comment: The MongoDB plugin being out of date was the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.